# How can I translate an element and at the same time rotate realistically?

Tags: html, css

It turns out of position and moves incorrectly. It's hard to find the exact point so it looks realistic and the transitions are smooth. the turning is out of cue and can not find a solution to make it turn faster as it moves at its normal rate. I have tried many times to get the exact timing but I cant find a way.

```js
function wid() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
    var r = document.querySelector(':root');
    r.style.setProperty('--wid', '100%');
  }
  wid();
}
```

```css
#car {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: translate(241.5px, 215px);
  position: relative;
  animation-name: driving;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  /*linear ease-in-out*/
}

#map {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(5%, 5%);
}

#bod {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mainsec {}

@keyframes driving {
  0% {
    transform: translate(241.5px, 215px);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(241.5px, 40px)rotate(-60deg);
  }
  28% {
    transform: translate(41.5px, 86px)rotate(-125deg);
  }
  38% {
    transform: translate(41.5px, 300px)rotate(-180deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(120px, 360px)rotate(-220deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(160px, 360px)rotate(-125deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(200px, 450px)rotate(-230deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(400px, 460px)rotate(-360deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(260.5px, 215pxrotate(360deg));
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(241.5px, 180pxrotate(360deg));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(241.5px, 215pxrotate(360deg));
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bod">
  <div id="map">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="415.00774" height="464.03421" viewBox="0,0,415.00774,464.03421">
      <g transform="translate(-5.56354,24.30861)">
        <g data-paper-data="{&quot;isPaintingLayer&quot;:true}" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
          <path d="M193.21864,323.70241c2.08101,14.58763 -0.75936,39.6034 -0.75936,39.6034l-76.95053,-59.65507c0,0 27.04231,-21.9967 43.16349,-20.31537c5.01955,0.5235 15.96324,3.86994 22.75063,11.80093c6.7874,7.93099 11.43447,26.03343 11.79578,28.56611z" fill="#e2ea8f" stroke="none"/>
          <path d="M5.56688,290.21195c0.51544,-15.25718 8.62251,-39.2653 8.62251,-39.2653l75.02651,85.4148c0,0 -34.79132,12.85441 -52.63063,5.75382c-5.55452,-2.21087 -17.2321,-9.2315 -23.32635,-19.42903c-6.09425,-10.19755 -7.78154,-29.82536 -7.69204,-32.47428z" fill="#e2ea8f" stroke="none"/>
          <path d="M219.05583,250.34734v-212.80012c0,0 1.48764,-14.0667 -3.9272,-17.72172c-5.41484,-3.65502 -26.47434,-0.83576 -26.47434,-0.83576l-66.30684,14.95228c0,0 -31.54844,6.49453 -43.16799,13.0135c-11.85598,6.65162 -17.65815,11.05621 -23.81015,25.35199c-6.15201,14.29579 -4.49552,155.45874 -4.49552,155.45874c0,0 0.12847,18.24631 2.32244,26.68213c1.97899,7.60918 18.15757,34.8776 33.34816,40.17712c19.19535,6.69665 43.22077,-3.09306 62.42146,3.17404c13.17719,4.30105 19.38737,8.26387 26.48485,18.94892c8.15443,12.27627 12.12432,31.97154 14.43416,37.56194c3.22503,7.80536 6.42812,17.86233 6.42812,17.86233l3.4807,18.08984c0,0 1.03251,15.13972 8.75099,18.80522c6.38845,3.03387 114.48707,3.64998 151.55195,3.77223c7.71664,0.02545 10.45146,1.27859 12.93151,-2.85614c1.26925,-2.11608 1.73211,-6.23932 -2.62668,-9.76101c-4.15809,-3.35953 -50.05552,-4.44025 -50.05552,-4.44025l8.83274,-34.13795c0,0 28.4294,-1.70463 51.65944,4.28594c23.23005,5.99057 28.02805,8.6783 34.85366,27.38878c4.72033,16.40398 10.64834,45.16217 -7.11765,45.35982c-60.58922,0.67405 -196.5872,1.94573 -217.63794,0.05149c-6.61359,-0.59513 -10.36459,-4.25214 -10.90643,-5.25027c-2.18537,-4.02565 -3.47544,-7.21102 -4.98448,-12.09238c-1.50902,-4.88135 -11.88057,-53.84601 -20.93852,-71.76255c-6.71889,-13.2899 -21.01689,-13.36816 -21.01689,-13.36816l-36.99995,-0.31926c0,0 -24.73763,1.62251 -39.7364,-10.8668c-11.6551,-9.70507 -19.2506,-18.21353 -27.99162,-32.54346c-8.74102,-14.32992 -9.25637,-22.76613 -12.14607,-33.25777c-2.88029,-10.45743 -3.43264,-33.62966 -3.43264,-33.62966c0,0 2.31202,-92.96558 1.9462,-152.4744c-0.07076,-11.51164 3.51657,-14.76709 6.12168,-20.3207c3.4054,-7.25967 10.81182,-13.80213 10.81182,-13.80213c0,0 19.26399,-15.40827 29.93019,-21.31454c10.50848,-5.81894 33.60085,-13.86497 33.60085,-13.86497l94.80812,-23.31008c0,0 15.46605,-4.62962 28.36495,-4.85435c11.96737,-0.2085 21.24293,3.77639 25.88139,8.78947c2.73367,2.95445 8.45832,9.73142 10.28464,14.53415c4.2386,11.14628 2.66852,21.78451 2.66852,21.78451v229.54004c0,0 -1.40764,17.5481 -0.50008,26.82662c0.34086,3.48486 4.70635,31.95634 21.05493,49.25219c15.8564,16.77515 51.49572,35.54486 51.49572,35.54486l-8.29877,33.81234c0,0 -16.52481,-0.78157 -32.88652,-13.95939c-14.69724,-7.65388 -27.17248,-17.57315 -36.41394,-27.55132c-16.40866,-17.71676 -22.39766,-35.61914 -24.07827,-41.35593c-5.39145,-18.40375 -8.51881,-62.56938 -8.51881,-62.56938z" fill="#414141" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M219.05583,165.09336v-5.97191h38.14575v5.97191z" fill="#d2d2d2" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M224.72917,199.44555v-1.40716h10.52976v1.40716z" fill="#d2d2d2" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M240.9985,199.47883v-1.40716h10.52976v1.40716z" fill="#d2d2d2" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M224.72915,169.62976v-1.40716h10.52976v1.40716z" fill="#d2d2d2" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M240.99849,169.66305v-1.40716h10.52976v1.40716z" fill="#d2d2d2" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M224.72915,184.69724v-1.40716h10.52976v1.40716z" fill="#d2d2d2" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M240.9985,184.73053v-1.40716h10.52976v1.40716z" fill="#d2d2d2" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M224.73546,228.96504v-1.40716h10.52976v1.40716z" fill="#d2d2d2" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M241.00479,228.99833v-1.40716h10.52976v1.40716z" fill="#d2d2d2" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M224.73546,214.21673v-1.40716h10.52976v1.40716z" fill="#d2d2d2" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M241.00479,214.25002v-1.40716h10.52976v1.40716z" fill="#d2d2d2" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M203.48125,23.23113l-0.09191,-5.49181c0,0 9.04848,-1.64122 13.01789,1.24562c2.86101,2.08074 4.05979,12.06922 4.05979,12.06922l-6.28979,0.0411c0,0 -0.42661,-5.56759 -3.14675,-7.23476c-2.27102,-1.39192 -7.54922,-0.62936 -7.54922,-0.62936z" fill="#bd0000" stroke="none"/>
          <path d="M207.96794,23.16086v-5.85189c0,0 2.70134,0.06002 4.01174,0.21819c1.25881,0.15192 3.70211,0.71279 3.70211,0.71279l-4.38891,5.71888c0,0 -1.13567,-0.40556 -1.69516,-0.53983c-0.5486,-0.13166 -1.62977,-0.25815 -1.62977,-0.25815z" fill="#bdbdbd" stroke="none"/><path d="M214.08583,31.1407l-0.66499,-3.85692l5.98488,-1.59597l0.93098,5.18691z" fill="#bdbdbd" stroke="none"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="car">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="5.69151" height="13.00614" viewBox="0,0,5.69151,13.00614">
      <g transform="translate(-237.15425,-173.49693)">
        <g data-paper-data="{&quot;isPaintingLayer&quot;:true}" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
          <path d="M237.95271,176.91509v-0.36484h1.65836v0.36484z" fill="#7e7e7e" stroke="none"/><path d="M240.4616,177.96722l-0.10174,-0.19425l1.68345,-0.8818l0.10175,0.19425z" data-paper-data="{&quot;index&quot;:null}" fill="#7e7e7e" stroke="none"/>
          <path d="M240.40631,176.94827v-0.36484h1.65836v0.36484z" data-paper-data="{&quot;index&quot;:null}" fill="#7e7e7e" stroke="none"/>
          <path d="M237.87231,177.05225l0.10177,-0.19425l1.68345,0.8818l-0.10174,0.19425z" fill="#7e7e7e" stroke="none"/>
          <path d="M237.68777,185.93213l0.07908,-4.54285l0.04206,-0.67016l0.26596,-0.28733c0,0 0.87932,-0.26451 1.13707,-0.61548c0.38158,-0.51961 0.30716,-1.61303 0.30716,-1.61303l0.13902,-3.00375l-0.57115,-0.00965l-0.80751,0.2432l-0.79069,-0.00484v-1.58791h2.20561l0.33641,-0.34338l0.34463,0.34338h2.13582v1.58791l-0.66608,0.00627l-0.80156,-0.27803l-0.63165,-0.00276l0.13298,3.04754c0,0 -0.04796,1.08621 0.37004,1.67854c0.27203,0.38548 1.01745,0.57779 1.01745,0.57779c0,0 0.22801,0.19788 0.25867,0.29475c0.03066,0.09686 0.03601,0.63613 0.03601,0.63613l0.08511,4.54371z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M237.15425,177.61095v-1.79988h0.82698v1.79988z" fill="#353535" stroke="none"/>
          <path d="M242.01878,177.65959v-1.79987h0.82697v1.79987z" fill="#353535" stroke="none"/>
          <path d="M237.15425,186.26759v-1.79987h1.0923v1.79987z" fill="#353535" stroke="none"/>
          <path d="M241.75344,186.31622v-1.79986h1.0923v1.79986z" fill="#353535" stroke="none"/>
          <path d="M238.35111,185.93798l0.0268,-1.54014l-0.65122,-0.69631l0.04014,-2.30639l0.04206,-0.67016l0.26596,-0.28734c0,0 0.87933,-0.26451 1.13708,-0.61549c0.38158,-0.51961 0.30716,-1.61302 0.30716,-1.61302l0.13902,-3.00375l0.03627,-1.35921l0.33641,-0.34338l0.34463,0.34338l0.03653,1.31338l0.13297,3.04753c0,0 -0.04796,1.08623 0.37004,1.67854c0.27203,0.38548 1.01745,0.57779 1.01745,0.57779c0,0 0.22801,0.19788 0.25867,0.29475c0.03066,0.09686 0.03602,0.63613 0.03602,0.63613l0.0426,2.27394l-0.64783,0.79572l0.06016,1.47404z" fill="#f30000" stroke="#000000"/>
          <path d="M238.82256,186.50307v-0.92868h2.35487v0.92868z" fill="#000000" stroke="none"/>
          <path d="M239.43365,180.99989v-1.46517c0,0 0.25408,-0.66824 0.56634,-0.65782c0.34514,0.01152 0.56635,0.65782 0.56635,0.65782v1.46517z" fill="#7e7e7e" stroke="none"/>
          <path d="M239.99999,180.68103c-0.17989,0 -0.32574,-0.16918 -0.32574,-0.37787c0,-0.20869 0.14583,-0.37787 0.32574,-0.37787c0.17989,0 0.32575,0.16918 0.32575,0.37787c0,0.20869 -0.14584,0.37787 -0.32575,0.37787z" fill="#f30000" stroke="none"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at [svg  motion paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion). You can move an element along a track.  There's also css property [`offset-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-path) - unfortunately still not supported in safari. Controlling the motion by manual keyframes is pretty complicated

Comment: Thank you herrstruetzel I went to some svg animation software and it worked!

Comment: Please take the [tour]. We don't mark posts [SOLVED] here.